# How am I supposed to use the footer-component outside of the slider component

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid, sections

so I'm currently working on a shopify website and I got a section which is the "featured collection", a part of the collection slider. The featured collection uses a "no-js" navigaiton counter. This counter counts the products to show and with the arrow you can navigate to the next products. 
Normally my Footer consists of: lookbook, shop, about

```
<div class="footer-row0" id="footerfalsch">
   <a href="/lookbook" class="lookbook" style="text-decoration: none;">lookbook</a>
   <a href="/shop" class="shop" style="text-decoration: none;">shop</a>
   <a href="/pages/about" class="about" style="text-decoration: none;">about</a>
 </div>
```

So I modificated the footer on the featured-collection and replaced the shop div with the pagination.

```
<div class="footer-row0">
   <a href="/lookbook" class="lookbook" style="text-decoration: none;">lookbook</a>
        <div class="slider-buttons no-js-hidden">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="slider-button slider-button--prev"
            name="previous"
            aria-label="{{ 'general.slider.previous_slide' | t }}"
            aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
          >
            {% render 'icon-caret' %}
          </button>
          <div class="slider-counter caption">
            <span class="slider-counter--current">1</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"> / </span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.slider.of' | t }}</span>
            <span class="slider-counter--total">{{ products_to_display }}</span>
          </div>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="slider-button slider-button--next"
            name="next"
            aria-label="{{ 'general.slider.next_slide' | t }}"
            aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
          >
            {% render 'icon-caret' %}
          </button>
        </div>

   <a href="/pages/about" class="about" style="text-decoration: none;">about</a>
 </div>
```

The div="slider-counter caption" is dependent of the `<slider-component>` and I find no way to place this outside the `<slider-component>` because then it shows no count.

> featured-collection.liquid

```html
{%- style -%}
  .section-{{ section.id }}-padding {
    padding-top: {{ section.settings.padding_top | times: 0.75 | round: 0 }}px;
    padding-bottom: {{ section.settings.padding_bottom | times: 0.75 | round: 0 }}px;
  }

  hr{
    border: 0.25px solid black;
  }

  
  slider-component.slider-mobile-gutter.slider-component-desktop{
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .slider-buttons.no-js-hidden{
  margin-left: -12px !Important;
  }slider-component#GalleryViewer-template--19556783751492__main

  @media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    .section-{{ section.id }}-padding {
      padding-top: {{ section.settings.padding_top }}px;
      padding-bottom: {{ section.settings.padding_bottom }}px;
    }
  }
{%- endstyle -%}

{%- liquid
  assign products_to_display = section.settings.collection.all_products_count

  if section.settings.collection.all_products_count > section.settings.products_to_show
    assign products_to_display = section.settings.products_to_show
    assign more_in_collection = true
  endif

  assign columns_mobile_int = section.settings.columns_mobile | plus: 0
  assign show_mobile_slider = false
  if section.settings.swipe_on_mobile and products_to_display > columns_mobile_int
    assign show_mobile_slider = true
  endif

  assign show_desktop_slider = false
  if section.settings.enable_desktop_slider and products_to_display > section.settings.columns_desktop
    assign show_desktop_slider = true
  endif
-%}
<div class="color-{{ section.settings.color_scheme }} isolate gradient">
  <div class="collection section-{{ section.id }}-padding{% if section.settings.full_width %} collection--full-width{% endif %}">
    <div class="collection__title title-wrapper title-wrapper--no-top-margin page-width{% if show_mobile_slider %} title-wrapper--self-padded-tablet-down{% endif %}{% if show_desktop_slider %} collection__title--desktop-slider{% endif %}">
      {%- if section.settings.title != blank -%}
        <h2 class="title inline-richtext {{ section.settings.heading_size }}{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}">
          {{ section.settings.title }}
        </h2>
      {%- endif -%}
      {%- if section.settings.description != blank
        or section.settings.show_description
        and section.settings.collection.description != empty
      -%}
        <div class="collection__description {{ section.settings.description_style }} rte{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}">
          {%- if section.settings.show_description -%}
            {{ section.settings.collection.description }}
          {%- else -%}
            {{ section.settings.description -}}
          {%- endif %}
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}
    </div>

    <slider-component class="slider-mobile-gutter{% if section.settings.full_width %} slider-component-full-width{% endif %}{% if show_mobile_slider == false %} page-width{% endif %}{% if show_desktop_slider == false and section.settings.full_width == false %} page-width-desktop{% endif %}{% if show_desktop_slider %} slider-component-desktop{% endif %}{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}">
      <div id="testfix">
      <ul
        id="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
        class="grid product-grid contains-card contains-card--product{% if settings.card_style == 'standard' %} contains-card--standard{% endif %} grid--{{ section.settings.columns_desktop }}-col-desktop{% if section.settings.collection == blank %} grid--2-col-tablet-down{% else %} grid--{{ section.settings.columns_mobile }}-col-tablet-down{% endif %}{% if show_mobile_slider or show_desktop_slider %} slider{% if show_desktop_slider %} slider--desktop{% endif %}{% if show_mobile_slider %} slider--tablet grid--peek{% endif %}{% endif %}"
        role="list"
        aria-label="{{ 'general.slider.name' | t }}"
      >
        {%- for product in section.settings.collection.products limit: section.settings.products_to_show -%}
          <li
            id="Slide-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index }}"
            class="grid__item{% if show_mobile_slider or show_desktop_slider %} slider__slide{% endif %}{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}"
            {% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %}
              data-cascade
              style="--animation-order: {{ forloop.index }};"
            {% endif %}
          >
            {% render 'card-product',
              card_product: product,
              media_aspect_ratio: section.settings.image_ratio,
              image_shape: section.settings.image_shape,
              show_secondary_image: section.settings.show_secondary_image,
              show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
              show_rating: section.settings.show_rating,
              show_quick_add: section.settings.enable_quick_add,
              section_id: section.id
            %}
          </li>
        {%- else -%}
          {%- for i in (1..4) -%}
            <li
              class="grid__item{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}"
              {% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %}
                data-cascade
                style="--animation-order: {{ forloop.index }};"
              {% endif %}
            >
              {%- assign placeholder_image = 'product-apparel-' | append: forloop.rindex -%}
              {% render 'card-product',
                show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
                placeholder_image: placeholder_image
              %}
            </li>
          {%- endfor -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
      </ul>
    </div>
 <div class="footer-row0">
   <a href="/lookbook" class="lookbook" style="text-decoration: none;">lookbook</a>
        <div class="slider-buttons no-js-hidden">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="slider-button slider-button--prev"
            name="previous"
            aria-label="{{ 'general.slider.previous_slide' | t }}"
            aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
          >
            {% render 'icon-caret' %}
          </button>
          <div class="slider-counter caption">
            <span class="slider-counter--current">1</span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"> / </span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.slider.of' | t }}</span>
            <span class="slider-counter--total">{{ products_to_display }}</span>
          </div>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="slider-button slider-button--next"
            name="next"
            aria-label="{{ 'general.slider.next_slide' | t }}"
            aria-controls="Slider-{{ section.id }}"
          >
            {% render 'icon-caret' %}
          </button>
        </div>

   <a href="/pages/about" class="about" style="text-decoration: none;">about</a>
 </div>
    </slider-component>

    {%- if section.settings.show_view_all and more_in_collection -%}
      <div class="center collection__view-all{% if settings.animations_reveal_on_scroll %} scroll-trigger animate--slide-in{% endif %}">
        <a
          href="{{ section.settings.collection.url }}"
          class="{% if section.settings.view_all_style == 'link' %}link underlined-link{% elsif section.settings.view_all_style == 'solid' %}button{% else %}button button--secondary{% endif %}"
          aria-label="{{ 'sections.featured_collection.view_all_label' | t: collection_name: section.settings.collection.title }}"
        >
          {{ 'sections.featured_collection.view_all' | t }}
        </a>
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
    {% if section.settings.image_shape == 'arch' %}
      {% render 'mask-arch' %}
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
</div>

      
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "t:sections.featured-collection.name",
  "tag": "section",
  "class": "section",
  "disabled_on": {
    "groups": ["header", "footer"]
  },
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "inline_richtext",
      "id": "title",
      "default": "Featured collection",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.title.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "heading_size",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "h2",
          "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "h1",
          "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "h0",
          "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "h1",
      "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "richtext",
      "id": "description",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.description.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_description",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_description.label",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "description_style",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.description_style.label",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "body",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.description_style.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "subtitle",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.description_style.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "uppercase",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.description_style.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "body"
    },
    {
      "type": "collection",
      "id": "collection",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.collection.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "products_to_show",
      "min": 2,
      "max": 25,
      "step": 1,
      "default": 4,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.products_to_show.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "columns_desktop",
      "min": 1,
      "max": 5,
      "step": 1,
      "default": 4,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.columns_desktop.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "full_width",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.full_width.label",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_view_all",
      "default": true,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_view_all.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "view_all_style",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.view_all_style.label",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "link",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.view_all_style.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "outline",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.view_all_style.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "solid",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.view_all_style.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "solid"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "enable_desktop_slider",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.enable_desktop_slider.label",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "color_scheme",
      "id": "color_scheme",
      "label": "t:sections.all.colors.label",
      "info": "t:sections.all.colors.has_cards_info",
      "default": "background-1"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.header.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "image_ratio",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "adapt",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.image_ratio.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "portrait",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.image_ratio.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "square",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.image_ratio.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "adapt",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.image_ratio.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "image_shape",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "default",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "arch",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "blob",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__3.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "chevronleft",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__4.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "chevronright",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__5.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "diamond",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__6.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "parallelogram",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__7.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "round",
          "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.options__8.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "default",
      "label": "t:sections.all.image_shape.label",
      "info": "t:sections.all.image_shape.info"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_secondary_image",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_secondary_image.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_vendor",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_vendor.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_rating",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_rating.label",
      "info": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.show_rating.info"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "enable_quick_add",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.enable_quick_buy.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.header_mobile.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "columns_mobile",
      "default": "2",
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.columns_mobile.label",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "1",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.columns_mobile.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "2",
          "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.columns_mobile.options__2.label"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "swipe_on_mobile",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.featured-collection.settings.swipe_on_mobile.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.all.padding.section_padding_heading"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "padding_top",
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100,
      "step": 4,
      "unit": "px",
      "label": "t:sections.all.padding.padding_top",
      "default": 36
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "padding_bottom",
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100,
      "step": 4,
      "unit": "px",
      "label": "t:sections.all.padding.padding_bottom",
      "default": 36
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "t:sections.featured-collection.presets.name"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Normally I have following css to center the products and let space between header and footer:

```
main{

display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
flex-direction: column;

}
```

Unfortanately the footer content mentioned above, also centers and therefore there is space unter the footer component.

[Click here to see how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjkLJ.png)

> Finally my Question:

How can I use the footer-row outside of the `slider-component`?
I tried to do it with css but obviously the footer-row is a child of main. When only using the `<div id="testfix">` and applying the css from the main to it, I have to set a `height`, and `100dvh` pushes the footer out of the viewport. Are there any other ways of fixing that with css or html? 
Working on it since literally 8 hours and I'm slowly starting to despair now.

Comment: bump this thread to the top

Comment: Not sure, but try to achieve with a separate section and footer section.